# Wordpress plugin or code to list content in a database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a CSV database of some group of peoples Name, Location, Contact  No., etc.
I'm finding a plugin or code to do this,
when a user select the location, list up the all the people (and their info) in that location with using CSV data

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried WP find my nearest?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-find-your-nearest/

I don't know if it can take data from a csv file, but its free, so you can always try it and see..